# Replace comma seperation with new line (jQuery JavaScript Library)

Tags: jquery

I am using the following example code here:
http://jsbin.com/ujuse

It uses the jQuery JavaScript Library.

How can I change it so that when you select a tick box, the comma is replaced with a new line instead? I need the text area to display:

one_name

one_name1

one_name2

Not as it does at the moment:

one_name,one_name1,one_name2

If anyone could help that would be brilliant as I have tried to download and edit the jQuery JavaScript Library myself with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), like this:

```
$('#t').val(allVals.join('\n'))
```

[You can test it here](http://jsbin.com/ujuse/28).  What's happening currently is since you're passing in an array to a string property, it's basically calling `.toString()`, which has the same effect as `.join(',')`, you can use a delimiter of your choice though, like newline in the code above.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much Nick.